# Security vulnerability in MySQL/MariaDB sql/password.c

Tags: mysql, mariadb

today while scaning my website it show this "Vulnerability in MySQL/MariaDB sql/password.c"

I dont understand what this is, and how to fix it.i googled it but i did not find much information on this problem.

Comment: Please be more specific, give more information...

Comment: scaning with acunetix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refers to a vulnerability reported in some builds of MySQL and derived products in June 2012.  The nature of the bug was that there was a 1 in 256 chance on each attempt to log in to MySQL, that it would authenticate your login attempt even if you give an incorrect password.

http://www.iss.net/security_center/reference/vuln/MySQL_Brute_Force.htm

The vulnerability manifests only if you build MySQL from source with non-default compiler flags.

Almost all binary packages of MySQL, MariaDB, and Percona Server were **safe**, that is they did **not** contain the vulnerability.

IIRC, some builds of MySQL for Ubuntu Linux were vulnerable, but that's only known binary distribution of MySQL or any derived product that was vulnerable.

The vulnerability is fixed in any case if you upgrade to version 5.1.63, 5.5.12, or 5.6.6, or later point-releases of each of these branches.

---

Re your comment:

You don't have to upgrade PHP.  This particular bug is in MySQL Server, not in PHP.

If you have a MySQL Server package that is vulnerable (only Ubuntu packages are vulnerable as far as I know), or you compiled MySQL Server from source yourself in a way that is vulnerable, then you should upgrade MySQL Server to at least one of the versions I list above.

Comment: thanks for the reply Bill. is there any way to fix it without upgrading the php version.